# Sum of values based on 2 columns in excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this excel sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yCZopo6_946knYyl_Ff8uuA2J0E9JUcGYO-gqUl88fk/edit#gid=0

If you check col G it's basically a uniqueness of col C, I simply want to sum the total in col H.

For example: 000294249 should give a total of : (30 + 5280 + 10) = 5320

I started with vlookup but it only returns the first value.

I think sumifs could work as well ... I'm not sure of the arguments though :

```
=SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try: `=SUMIFS(D2:D11,C2:C11,G2:G6)` or `=SUMIFS(D2:D11,C2:C11,G2)` fill down

Comment: You say "I have this Excel sheet" and then promptly link to a Google Sheet. Please realise these are NOT the same thing. While there is an overlap and you can open GSheets with Excel and vice versa, there are many differences and incompatibilities. You should only tag with Excel if you are using Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this formula that checks the unique `DIN` values and then calculates the sum of the corresponding `QT` values for each unique `DIN`

### Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(C2:C11, UNIQUE(C2:C11), D2:D11))
```

### Output:

[image]

### References:

[SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad I could be of help!

Comment: What would the equivalent of this be in excel?

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY()` function would be best fit in this case. You may try-

```
=QUERY(C:D,"select C, sum(D) where C is not null group by C",1)
```

[image]